# Reference parameters to return information VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, url-rewriting, division

One last question for tonight. How would I go about re-writing this code to no longer return the quotient through the return value but rather use a reference parameter to return information about the quotient?

```
Function divideInputs(ByVal dividend As Integer, ByVal divisor As Integer) As Double
  Dim quotient As Integer = 1
quotient = dividend / divisor
Return quotient
End Function
```

Comment: Add another argument, but use `ByRef` instead of `ByVal`. Assign to it in the body of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub divideInputs(ByVal dividend As Integer, ByVal divisor As Integer, ByRef quotient As Integer)
    quotient = dividend / divisor
End Sub
```

Then to call the logic, do this:

```
Dim q As Integer
divideInputs(6, 3, q)
```

Comment: would it also be possible to just do function instead of sub and allocate the memory as a double?

Comment: @user2860326 - if you are going to use a `Function`, then just return the value, since that is one of the main differences between a `Function` and a `Sub` in VB.NET.